# pandas dataframe.to_csv() have extra commas in the column

Tags: python, pandas

Sometimes when I do

```
data_frame.to_csv(tab_name + '.csv', encoding="utf-8", index=False) # dataframe get from internal API call, so can't shown here
```

the result csv file has many extra commas in the column.

An example file:

```
accountid,account_manager

001a000001JdbicAAB,,,,,,,,,005a0000009seCqAAI
```

The extra commas shouldn't be there. Not sure how to get rid of them..

Comment: what does `date_frame.columns.tolist()` show? You may have more columns than you realise or you have cell that just has a load of commas

Comment: You may drop empty columns http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html ... buy you must analyse your case first